# Merge matriz biológica y matriz con etiquetas

Tags: r

Quiero hacer un merge entre un data.frame de datos biológicos (es decir una lista de especies con sus correspondientes abundancias) y otra matriz con una etiqueta para cada especie... con el fin de cuando quiera realizar un plot, no realizarlo por especies, si no por estas etiquetas que pueden ser comunes a varias especies.

```
COM
Antant  Apoimb  Athpres Athspp  Blenni  Booboo  Chelab
10              75  
5                   
5               300 
21              400 
6               500 
9               100 

TROPHIC
        TG
Antant  PL
Apoimb  PL
Athpres PL
Athspp  PL
Blenni  CA
Booboo  PL
Chelab  DE
```

Intenté lo siguiente pero sin éxito:

```
`temp=merge(COM, TROPHIC, by = c("TG"), all.x=T, sort = FALSE)`
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
```

Como podría hacer el merge?

Comment: Interesante pregunta, Alejandro. Para que la gente se anime a contestar es importante que nos expliques qué has intentado hasta la fecha, así como por qué no te funcionó. Así nos evitamos transitar caminos que tú ya recorriste.

Comment: @fedorqui He intentado lo siguiente, pero sin éxito     `temp=merge(COM, TROPHIC, by = c("TG"), all.x=T, sort = FALSE)
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column`  COM es la matriz biológica, y TROPHIC la matriz de las etiquetas

Comment: Ajá, ¡qué bien! Lo que deberías hacer entonces es incorporar este código a la pregunta, utilizando [edit].

Comment: Alejandro, por lo que entiendo `COM` es un `data.frame` dónde cada columna se corresponde con una fila de `TROPHIC`. Esto efectivamente es así? Y en definitiva lo que buscas es tener las sumas de especies por cada `TG`?

Comment: Exacto! Me gustaría que cada columna de COM tuviese aplicada la etiqueta TROPHIC que le corresponde.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar voy a preparar un ejemplo en base a la información que aportaste, te sugiero que cuando quieras compartir información uses las función `dput()` por ejemplo `dput(head(COM))` ya que esto genera un "script" para generar exactamente el objeto que quieres compartir, con su clase, con el tipo exacto para cada columna, con factores si los tiene, etc.

```
COM <- read.table(text="
Antant  Apoimb  Athpres Athspp  Blenni  Booboo  Chelab
10      75      0       0       0       0       0  
5       0       0       0       0       0       0  
5       300     0       0       0       0       0  
21      400     0       0       0       0       0   
6       500     0       0       0       0       0  
9       100     0       0       0       0       0  ", skip=1, header=TRUE)

TROPHIC <- read.table(text="
RN TG
Antant  PL
Apoimb  PL
Athpres PL
Athspp  PL
Blenni  CA
Booboo  PL
Chelab  DE
", skip=1, header=TRUE)

rownames(TROPHIC) <- TROPHIC[,1]
TROPHIC <- TROPHIC[2]
```

Por lo que finalmente tendríamos lo siguiente:

```
> COM
  Antant Apoimb Athpres Athspp Blenni Booboo Chelab
1     10     75       0      0      0      0      0
2      5      0       0      0      0      0      0
3      5    300       0      0      0      0      0
4     21    400       0      0      0      0      0
5      6    500       0      0      0      0      0
6      9    100       0      0      0      0      0
> TROPHIC
       RN TG
1  Antant PL
2  Apoimb PL
3 Athpres PL
4  Athspp PL
5  Blenni CA
6  Booboo PL
7  Chelab DE
```

Revisa por favor, que los datos se correspondan efectivamente con tus estructuras.

#### Solución:

Si en definitiva lo que buscas es llegar a un total por etiqueta, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
COM <- as.data.frame(cbind(Total=colSums(COM)))
FINAL <- as.data.frame(cbind(COM, TG=TROPHIC[match(rownames(COM), rownames(TROPHIC)),]))
aggregate(. ~ TG, FINAL, sum)
```

#### Resultado Final:

```
  TG Total
1 CA     0
2 DE     0
3 PL  1431
```

#### Detalle:

- En primer lugar, con `COM <- as.data.frame(cbind(Total=colSums(COM)))` generamos un nuevo `data.frame` con la suma para cada especie, algo así:

  ```
          Total
  Antant     56
  Apoimb   1375
  Athpres     0
  Athspp      0
  Blenni      0
  Booboo      0
  Chelab      0
  ```
- Con `as.data.frame(cbind(COM, TG=TROPHIC[match(rownames(COM), rownames(TROPHIC)),]))` le agregamos a cada especie la etiqueta que le corresponde, algo así:

  ```
          Total TG
  Antant     56 PL
  Apoimb   1375 PL
  Athpres     0 PL
  Athspp      0 PL
  Blenni      0 CA
  Booboo      0 PL
  Chelab      0 DE
  ```
- Y por último, con `aggregate(. ~ TG, FINAL, sum)` agrupamos por cada etiqueta y obtenemos la suma final:

  ```
    TG Total
  1 CA     0
  2 DE     0
  3 PL  1431
  ```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a todos los que habéis aportado vuestro granito de arena!

Answer (score 0):

Una aproximación alternativa usando `dplyr`.

## Reproduzco los `data.frame` que hizo Patricio.

```
COM <- read.table(text="
Antant  Apoimb  Athpres Athspp  Blenni  Booboo  Chelab
10      75      0       0       0       0       0  
5       0       0       0       0       0       0  
5       300     0       0       0       0       0  
21      400     0       0       0       0       0   
6       500     0       0       0       0       0  
9       100     0       0       0       0       0  ", skip=1, header=TRUE)

TROPHIC <- read.table(text="
RN TG
Antant  PL
Apoimb  PL
Athpres PL
Athspp  PL
Blenni  CA
Booboo  PL
Chelab  DE
", skip=1, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Nótese que no cambio los `rownames` y que paso el argumento `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` para evitar pasar a factor directamente en la importación. No es **necesario**, pero evita un `warning` en `inner_join()`.

## Manipulación y sumario de datos:

```
COM %>% 
  gather(RN, valor) %>%           #Paso a formato largo, hago coincidir el nombre de la columna con el TROPHIC.
  inner_join(TROPHIC) %>%         #join de COM y TROPHIC, la columna RN está en ambos data.frame y por defaul es la clave del join. 
  group_by(TG) %>%                #agrupo, aplicará el sumario de la siguiente línea a cada uno de los grupos definidos aquí. 
  summarise(Total = sum(valor))   #Sumatoria de valor para cada grupo.
```

## Resultado:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     TG Total
  <chr> <int>
1    CA     0
2    DE     0
3    PL  1431
```